# unable to install rpm packages in gnome3 (openSUSE 12.1)

Tags: opensuse, software-installation, gnome3

I have to install wicd from its source rpm package but `Apper-sentinel` keeps waiting at `license agreement requirement` showing message `waiting for service to start`.

[This](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/469905-skype-keeps-waiting-service-start-onstall.html) (see the last comment in this post) thread has the solution from KDE session, but i can't find anything similar to configure-destop > file associations in GNOME-3 anywhere to move up "Install/Remove Software"..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to fix your problem

### 1. Adjust the application used to open the RPM

- Download an RPM, any RPM
- Right click on it and go to properties
- Go to the *Open With* tab
- Adjust as needed

My defaults are at the end of the answer

### 2. Use the `zypper` command-line tool to install the downloaded RPM

In a console, run `zypper in file.rpm`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Robert. 'Open With' tab has 4 installer options,
1st triggers `/usr/bin/gpk-install-local-file`
and other 3 open `Apper`.. And i end up back to the same problem i originally had..

Comment: I have a completely different set of applications ( will update the answer ). If you can't install it using the GUI, I suggest that you drop to the command line and use `sudo zypper in file.rpm` .